# CMake can't find libevent on macOS

Tags: cmake, libevent

I've installed libevent on macOS -

```
$ brew install libevent
```

I'm trying to import it in my CMakeLists.txt -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(xyz)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(libevent REQUIRED)
```

I get the following CMake error -

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibevent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libevent",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libevent" with any
  of the following names:

    libeventConfig.cmake
    libevent-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libevent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libevent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libevent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Could someone please tell how to import libevent installed in the system in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble but I work arond this by adding:

```
link_directories(
  /usr/local/lib
  /usr/lib
)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  /usr/local/include/
  /usr/include
)
```

It just tell the Makefile where to find libevent header and library.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must install pkg-config

   ```
   brew install pkg-config
   ```
2. then in CMakeList.txt

   ```
   find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)
   if(PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
       pkg_search_module(LIBEVENT libevent )
       if (LIBEVENT_FOUND)
           message(STATUS "Found libevent ${LIBEVENT_FOUND}")
           message(STATUS "libevent inc : ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
           message(STATUS "libevent lib : ${LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES}")
       endif ()
   endif()

   # ...
   add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MacOS then this should work:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EVENT_LIBRARIES})
```

Brew's libevent package is stored in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libevent/2.1.12_1` for example.